# Hard drive error (3F0) on HP 250 G3

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, ubuntu-16.04

I am getting this error when i try to boot my laptop

> Boot Device Not Found Hard drive error (3F0) Please install operating system

I tried to do hard drive check by pressing F2 and it shows me

> smart check and short DST not installed.

Looks like it doesn't recognize my hard drive, i am using Ubuntu and SSD which is new, I bought it a month ago.

Legacy support was enabled (by default) when i install Ubuntu and everything was working well until yesterday. I found on HP forums that this error occurred because legacy support isnt enabled, but mine was enabled

What can i do ?

Comment: Why did you enabled "legacy"? Ubuntu can and should be installed in UEFI mode. That's probably the reason for "boot device not found".

Comment: Please clarify the timeline.  I assume it’s been working OK for the past month; am I right?  When did you enable legacy in BIOS?  Last night?  Or weeks ago?  I.e., has it been working in legacy mode?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The 3fo error code indicates a potential issue with the HDD/SSD. Try going into your BIOS (press delete at startup) and check if it detects anything under SATA or IDE.
The next two steps i would recommend would be testing another hdd in the computer and/or testing the existing hdd in another computer.

most likely the hdd is damaged but there is potential for the motherboard/sata controller to be damaged/faulty.

Sources:

*1 https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Hard-drive-not-found-3F0-error/td-p/1406345

*2 https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/My-PC-is-saying-Boot-Device-not-found-Hard-Disk-3FO/td-p/778869

Comment: SSD wasnt properly connected to motherboard, but i fix that and now its working well